# Syntax translate

Tags: mysql

this is my code :

```
CREATE TRIGGER Zmiana_kategorii
ON Hotele
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @stara smallint, @nowa smallint
    IF COL_LENGTH('deleted', 'IloscGwiazdek')
    BEGIN
    SET @stara=(SELECT IloscGwiazdek FROM deleted)
    SET @nowa=(SELECT IloscGwiazdek FROM inserted)
        IF(@stara<@nowa)
        BEGIN
        print 'Powiadom następujących klientów o zmianie klasy hotelu'
        declare @data date
        SET @data=(CONVERT (date, GETDATE()))
        SELECT KlientID FROM Rezerwacje Where @data<DataPrzyjazdu
        END
    END

END
```

could someone tell me what is wrong in syntax? I am 1st time using MYSQL i have no clue whats is wrong with this...

this is error : ON Hotele AFTER UPDATE AS BEGIN DECLARE @stara smallint, @nowa smallint ' at line 2" this is error

Comment: Best clue would probably be an error message MySQL gives to you when you try to execute this.

Comment: First, `MySQL` doesn't support the function `COL_LENGTH`.

Comment: Are we expected to just guess what's wrong with a trigger written in a foreign language we don't even know what's supposed to do?

Comment: Are you sure about your use of `DELIMITER`>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one problem is that you don't include the `THEN` after your `IF` conditions. For example:

```
IF (@stara<@nowa) THEN
BEGIN
    -- ...
END
```

Another problem is that you have the order of the `CREATE TRIGGER` elements wrong. It should be:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Zmiana_kategorii
AFTER UPDATE
ON Hotele
```

Note that the `AFTER UPDATE` goes before the `ON`. This seems to solve your specific problem.

Finally, MySQL doesn't have a `PRINT` command and all variables have to be declared at the beginning of a `BEGIN` block, before any other statements.

Please read this entire page and understand what's going on: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

If you understand the syntax, then you can debug it yourself. These types of simple problems shouldn't require community assistance (though sometimes an extra pair of eyes can catch an obvious error).